# Force anonymous logon to SMB share with New-PSDrive

Tags: windows, powershell, smb

How can I use the `New-PSDrive` command in Windows PowerShell 5.0 September 2014 Preview to force an anonymous logon to a SMB share? I'm using a Windows 10 Server Technical Preview VM in Azure to connect back to my Windows 8.1 Professional 64-bit laptop, over a point-to-site (P2S) VPN connection (not that, that really matters).

I've tried using the username `NTAUTHORITY\Anonymous Logon` with and without a password. If I use it with a password, I get:

> New-PSDrive : The user name or password is incorrect

If I leave the password blank, I get:

> New-PSDrive : Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Here is the script I'm using:

```
$PSDrive = @{
    Credential = Get-Credential -UserName 'NTAUTHORITY\Anonymous Logon' -Message 'Please enter your password';
    Root =  '\\cid-win81\windows10';
    PSProvider = 'FileSystem';
    Name = 'smbtest';
    };

New-PSDrive @PSDrive;
```

Comment: to ask the obvious: have you tried just connecting with no Credential parameter? Its not mandatory. Or does it then try to authenticate with your current user?

Comment: It tries to use the Windows default credential, if you don't specify the `-Credential` parameter. Not a dumb question, but I have considered that.

Comment: can you even make server 10 allow to connect anonymously? Just wondering since you cannot create fileshares that are accessible without credentials on win 8 afaik, on our servers i didnt try though

Comment: ridiculously enough it works on my server 10 test instance when i add "everyone" (dont forget ntfs permissions). BUT only if joined to a domain, if it is only joined to a workgroup it won´t work

Comment: Paul - thanks for the responses. Yes, it would work in a domain environment, but my laptop and the server are both workgroup systems. They don't trust each others' identity stores (user accounts), so I can't use the default credential to authenticate. I have to use an explicit credential, whether that's anonymous, or a separate user account I create just for this purpose.

Comment: i dont necessarily think it´s because of the missing trust because i accessed the share both of the time from my private pc (which is neither domain-joined nor part of the same workgroup as the test server)

Comment: If the username/passwords coincidentally match, then it will work. Is that perhaps what occurred in your test?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63566/discussion-between-paul-and-trevor-sullivan).

Comment: Did you solve this? I am encountering the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

When authentication with a Windows 10 workstation PC to a samba-share which requires no logon, Try using l/p: guest/guest